# .anaconda folder is taking too much space

Tags: python, directory, anaconda, local-storage, delete-file

I have installed `anaconda` in my D: drive because my SSD(C: drive) is only 128 GB. yesterday I saw that I only left with 9 GB of space in my C: drive and .anaconda is taking 35.9 GB of space to be more specific (`.anaconda/navigatior/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/notebook-err-1.txt` and `notebook-err-2.txt`) each of them is around 18 GB. Can I just delete it?

Attaching the image below for reference
[image: notebook-err files]

Comment: If your work doesn't necessarily requires you to have anaconda just uninstall it, you can still do pretty much everything with vanilla python

Answer (score 7):

You probably should not delete this directly (although it might be safe, IDK). Here are several approaches that should free up quite a bit of memory if you have not used these before:

`conda clear -all`
Remove stored, but already installed `tarballs`,
old packages that were upgraded and are kept "just in case!?"
svn cacne, hg cache, git cache, source cache.

`conda clean -all`
Remove index cache, lock files, unused cache packages, and tarballs.

`conda remove -n myenv scipy`
remove a package such as SciPy in an environment such as myenv:

`conda remove scipy`
remove a package such as SciPy in the current environment:

`conda remove --envname`
remove virtual environments you do not use.

more info on [conda clean](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/clean.html), [conda remove](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html)

Comment: conda clean -a -y